# How to fix the loop?

Tags: c, loops, fgetc

I need a program to get the input from a file using `fgetc`. The first condition is to find the newline `'\n'` then copy all the characters. After that, if you encounter a comma `','` the program needs to stop copying.

My code compiles but when I run it, nothing happens; the cursor just blinks infinitely.

```
do  {
        if (copy != '\n')
            {
            copy = fgetc(mp);
            }
        else
            {
            for (i=0; copy != ','; i++) //i is a counter                {
                player_name[i] = copy;
                copy = fgetc(mp);
                }
            }
        }
    while (copy != EOF);

printf("%c", player_name);
```

Help?

Comment: There is no output in this code, which is why you see nothing. Add some [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) statements.

Comment: Change that %c in the printf to %s

Comment: Sorry. I already edited it.

Comment: Also, after you're done reading all your characters, add a 0 to player_name to indicate end of string. So right after the for loop, I'd put `player_name[i] = 0`. And the way the loop is set up right now, after the first `player_name` has been read, it will see that `copy != EOF` and will seek another newline, after which it will overwrite the first player_name.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `printf` if you want to see the output:

```
do  {
    if (copy != '\n')
        {
        copy = fgetc(mp);
        }
    else
        {
        for (i=0; copy != ','; i++) //i is a counter                {
            player_name[i] = copy;
            printf("%c",player_name[i]);
            copy = fgetc(mp);
            }

         player_name[i] = '\0'; // impliment this if you want to convert player name into a string to be used later 
        }
    }
while (copy != EOF);
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your structure. After running that, copy does indeed equal what you want it to. But you haven't told the computer what to do with that var. Do you want to print? Write to another file?

Tell the computer to do something with copy.